# Split activity with adjustable children height

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create an activity layout with two parts, where their respective size is dynamic. The activity should have two states:

Starting state:

[image]

The user scrolls the bottom part up to the second state (and back):

[image]

It's important that the change will be animated. I tried a few solutions so far but didn't manage to find the exact way to do that:

1. [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) - The panel acts as another layout, covering the upper view and moving the toolbar out of the screen.
2. [Android Split Pane Layout](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout) - Correct behavior, but the splitter is dragged and not the bottom part (I don't want to have a visible splitter).
3. CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout - I didn't find a way to limit the upper part from totally disappearing. Anyway I think that it's a bit abusing because I don't want to collapse a toolbar but just change the children's height with animation.

Is there a good way to implement this using another library, one of these that I perhaps didn't use correctly or with simple layouts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [custom version](https://code.videolan.org/sv244/vlc-android/blob/3b8b900d4e7ec06d46b463d38ea1f36e251a8da1/vlc-android/src/org/videolan/vlc/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.java) of the [SlidingPaneLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) created by VLC, which is basically a vertical SlidingPaneLayout - the exact functionality that I was looking for.